# Using SQL Server profiler from 2008 against R2 database

Tags: sql-server-2008

On my dev machine I have the management studio tools installed from SQL Server 2008.  However, one of the sql server boxes I need to profile against is running R2.

Because of this, when I start the profiler and connect to that server all of the templates are gone.

If I go to Edit the templates, the R2 server type isn't available as an option.

Do I have to upgrade my local toolset to R2 or is there some other way around this?

Note, that if I create a template and save it the next time I connect to the server that saved template isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, SQL client tools are backwards compatible to older server version but not forwards compatible. This isn't 100% true (SQL EM could not manage SQL Server 2005 but Query Analyzer worked) but I've found it a good rule of thumb.

I'd upgrade my SQL tools.

Or can you remote into a box running R2 and run profiler there as a workaround?

Comment: Looks like upgrading is the only real option. Thanks.